# Bootstrap indicator thumbnail selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a Bootstrap carousel and thumbnails indicator but I don't know why the 2nd thumbnail is always selected. I'm using bootstrap 3.0

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/xuhP9/

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
});

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
id = parseInt(id);
$('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
});

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
id = parseInt(id);
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
$('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solved of your problem.

Solution : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imjaypatel/xuhP9/15)

**old code**

```
<div class="item" data-slide-to="1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

**new code**

```
<div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

your mistake is wrong assign class **data-slide-to="1"** . i replace to **data-slide-number="1"**.

another is close all <**img**> tag properly. its highlight to a invalid coding validation.